# How can I set my Server Fault flair to show in the employer search result in Careers?

Tags: discussion, jobs, flair

When I look at Employer View, the Employer Search Result example shows my SO "flair" and link (even if I select to hide it on my CV). I **do** want to include my SO rep and link, but I want my SF one to be primary since I'm a sysadmin. How can I do that?

Comment: Heh heh... Yeah-- my Stack Overflow flair is rather, well, embarassing. My Server Fault flair, OTOH...

Comment: No idea why a suggested improvement to the Careers site was migrated to mSF.

Comment: The [status-planned] tag apparently didn't follow the migration.

Answer (score 3):

To show whatever flair one could just add it on top of a personal statement.

- That's about how it could look in employers view:

  > [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK2lE.jpg]
- that's how to edit the flair code on top of personal statement:

  > [image]

---

URL to edit personal statement at Careers is:

```
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/<your Careers id>?FormName=PersonalStatement
```

- For the sake of completeness, URL to get code for SF flair is: `<your SF profile URL>/flair`

Comment: +1 Hand drawn red circles and arrows